# jScroll.js with Laravel 5: nextSelector not found - destroying

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, pagination

I am using a combination of jscroll.js, jquery.upvote.js and Laravel's `paginate()` method. It all works except for this little thing, the last post in the pagination page always has unclickable voting buttons.

No errors in the developer's console either.

At the moment, I'm using `paginate(2)` because I only have 3 posts in the category.

**EDIT:** I just added a few more posts and noticed that the voting buttons only work on the first page, the rest of the pages are rendering the vote buttons unclickable.

**EDIT 2:** I turned on `debug: true` in jscroll.js and I'm getting this new error

> jScroll: nextSelector not found - destroying

The "next" selector markup looks like this

```
<a href="24?page=2" rel="next">»</a>
```

[image]

If I remove `paginate(2)` and jscroll.js all voting buttons start functioning properly.

`SubredditController`

```
$subreddit = Subreddit::with('posts.votes')->with('moderators.user')->where('id', $subreddit->id)->first();
$posts = $subreddit->posts()->paginate(2);
```

The view

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/jquery.upvote.css') }}">
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/jquery.upvote.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('assets/js/jquery.jscroll.min.js') }}"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.topic').upvote();

            $('.vote').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var $button = $(this);
                var postId = $button.data('post-id');
                var value = $button.data('value');
                $.post('http://localhost/reddit/public/votes', {postId:postId, value:value}, function(data) {
                    if (data.status == 'success')
                    {
                        // Do something if you want..
                    }
                }, 'json');
            });

            $('.scroll').jscroll({
                autoTrigger: true,
                nextSelector: '.pagination li.active + li a',
                contentSelector: 'div.scroll',
                callback: function() {
                    $('ul.pagination:visible:first').hide();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

<div class="scroll">
   @foreach($posts as $post)
        @include('partials/post')
   @endforeach
   {!! $posts->render() !!}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any new elements being created after the initial page will need to have the click events assigned to them also.

```
// transform anonymous function to real and reusable one
function voteClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $button = $(this);
    var postId = $button.data('post-id');
    var value = $button.data('value');
    $.post('http://localhost/reddit/public/votes', {postId:postId, value:value}, function(data) {
        if (data.status == 'success')
        {
            // Do something if you want..
        }
    }, 'json');
}

$('.vote').on('click', 'voteClick'); // use new function here

$('.scroll').jscroll({
    autoTrigger: true,
    nextSelector: '.pagination li.active + li a',
    contentSelector: 'div.scroll',
    callback: function() {
        $('ul.pagination:visible:first').hide();
        $('.vote').on('click', voteClick); // add this to apply the event to all of your .vote elements again.
    }
});
```

Comment: I do not understand, I already have an on.click event, where else should I have it? Should I put the `$('.scroll').jscroll()` inside the on.click even?

Comment: Your on click event is only applied to the initial elements on the page (load). For every new element that is added by the jscroll, you'll need to add the click event (`$('.vote').on('click')`) to it.

Comment: I don't understand how's that gonna work. A small code example maybe?

Comment: I added some example code. In the example I simply reapply the on click event to all elements. You'll probably want to only apply it to the newly created ones.

Comment: I tried putting that in the callback function of `$('.scroll')` but that didn't change anything.

Comment: I accidentally included the function name as a string. Try removing the quotes from 'voteClick'.

Comment: I just tried your code, the error in the console is gone, but the buttons of the next pages are still unclickable. Yes, I remove the quotes from the function name too.

Comment: I'm guessing it's because the new elements don't actually have the .vote class on them.

Comment: New elements do have `vote` class on them, just checked. Your function has sort of messed up with the voting mechanism a little. Voting persistence is gone.

Comment: It's still not working and the award is going to expire in 45 mins, can you please have another look at the code so I can award you the points and the correct answer? Thank you.